# getting java.io.NotSerializableException while writing the object which is having a Vector attribute

Tags: java, vector

I have one class `State`  which is having a vector variable state and setting a vector list of state in its setter function

```
class State implement Serializable{  
    private Vector state;  
    //its getters and setters  
}
```

In `class B` I am getting the `State` class from the session and then assigning it to same `State` object and then using `writeObject` method for this class.

```
class B {  
       State _state  = (State) session.getAttribute("_stateKey");  
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
       ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);  
       oos.writeObject(_state); // at this line i am getting java.io.NotSerializableException
    }
```

Someone please help me on this why i am getting this error...

Comment: What types of objects are you storing in `state`?  Is one of those types not serializable?

Comment: What are you putting into the `Vector`? The objects that you put in there have to be `Serializable` too. And, you shouldn't use `Vector`, because it's a legacy collection class. Use `ArrayList` instead. Also, use generics.

Comment: The NotSerializableException should tell you exactly which class is the culprit.

Comment: @Jesper- Is there any way i can typecast an Array List to vector. Its an old code and i have to use vector only because list what i am putting in this vector is also of Vector type. Earlier we were using String and that time everything was fine but after changing to Vector this error strts. Is it something with the oos.writeObject(_state); Is wrightObject method do not allow a class to write if any attribute in that calss is a Vector?

Answer (score 2):

Your class should implement the `Serializable Interface`, because `Vector` does implement that. So the problem is with your own `Class`.

Comment: That also i tried by implementing Serializable Interface on class B but still having the same issue.

Comment: then it means you've other objects, which are not serializable.

Comment: it looks like the object in vector does not implements **Serializable**  interface. it has nothing to do with Class B

Comment: yeah may be. Any object in `Class B` or in the `Vector`, which is not serializable, will cause that error.

Comment: @user1782009 - Can you post the full stack trace? It'll give a more clear idea as to which object is the culprit for this.

Comment: @R.J- I have a cacth block   catch(NotSerializableException e)  {  log.trace("Exception"+ e)}  because of this i am not getting any stack trace as such. Only getting java.io.NotSerializableException: com.xyz.abc.LookUp

Comment: give a `e.printStackTrace();` below your logger.

Comment: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.pmi.epmi.LookUp
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1355)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1163)
      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:144)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1686)
      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:468)       at java.util.Vector.writeObject(Vector.java:1081)

Comment: Thank you all. I resolved the issue. I did not implmented Serializable Interface on one class from where i was getting one value which i was putting in the list. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I resolved the issue. I did not implmented Serializable Interface on one class from where i was getting one value which i was putting in the list. Thanks for your suggestions